# #include <cstdatomic> "no such file" in ubuntu

Tags: c++

when compile with g++ -std=c++0x -Wall test.cc -o hello, 
output fatal error:  cstdatomic  No such file or directly

Where is missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The include should be `#include <atomic>`